# The boundary of $(-1,2)\cup[3,\infty)$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to determine the boundary of $S=(-1,2)\cup [3,\infty)$ within $\mathbb{R}$.

I thought that the set of boundary points would be all the points which contain an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood that has points in $S$ and points not in $S$. I thought that the only place that would be was $3$ because at $-1$ and $2$ you could have an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood small enough such that it would be fully contained in $S$ as these are limit points. Any explanation why the answer is given as $\{-1,2,3\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-1$ is a boundary set because the following is true:

> For every $\epsilon > 0$, the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $-1$ includes both points in $S$ and points outside $S$.

---

Where you made your mistake is when you wrote the following:

> at $-1$ and $2$ you could have an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood small enough such that it would be fully contained in $S$

This is not true.

---

More importantly, where you made your mistake is you wrote something **without being certain if it is correct**. In general, if you think $A$ is true because $B$ is true, you should always try to prove that $B$ is, in fact true. Without that proof, all you have is a hypothesis.

Comment: Isn't $-1$ a limit point though? Which means it could have an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood which could be fully contained in S? Therefore it wouldn't have points that are outside S?

Comment: @DogmanDogman Yes, $-1$ is a limit point. Why would that mean it has a neighborhood fully contained in $S$? Also, any neighborhood of $-1$ contains $-1$. Therefore, because $-1\notin S$, every neighborhood of $-1$ contains points outside $S$...

Comment: My bad, I got it mixed up with interior points. I understand your explanation now. Thank you :)

Comment: @DogmanDogman My advice for next time: If you think that $-1$ has a neighborhood fully contained in $S$, then try to actually write that neighborhood down! You should very quickly be able to see this is not true. And this is true in general. Whenever you think something exists, try to construct that thing.

Comment: Your edit on your reply to my first comment was very helpful seeing the neighbourhood of $-1$. It makes it very obvious to see that $-1$'s neighbourhood contains points outside of $S$ because it isn't in $S$ itself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$S=(-1,2)\cup [3,\infty)$. Let $\partial S$ be the boundary of $S$. By definition:
$$\partial S = \overline{S} / int(S)$$
and
$$\overline{S} = [-1,2] \cup[3,\infty]$$

$$int(S) = (-1,2)\cup(3,\infty) \implies$$

$$\partial S = \overline{S} / int(S) = \{1,2,3\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter how small ε-neighborhood of -1 you choose, you'll always get points from both inside and outside of S. You can divide the interval (-1-ε,-1+ε) into two parts, (-1-ε,-1) and (-1,-1+ε). All the points in (-1,-1+ε), belong to S, but every point of (-1-ε,-1) is outside S (regardless of choice of ε). So we can clearly see that -1 is a boundary point (even though it does not belong to the set S). With similar arguments you can also check that 2 and 3 are also boundary points. And hence, the boundary of S is {-1,2,3}. I hope it will clear your doubt:)